# Append R variable inside SQLDF's SQL code

Tags: sql, r, sqldf

Tried to search for an answer using "SQLDF append in code", but I couldnt find any answer.

Basically, I'd like to be able to write something like that :

```
divisor<-4
result<-sqldf("SELECT id, some_number/ " . divisor . " FROM my_table")
```

but I can't find a way to have `divisor` included in the SQL statement : `Error: unexpected symbol in "result<-sqldf("SELECT id, some_number/ " ."`

I tried having `&`, `+` and `nothing` instead of the dots `.`, but I can't find anything that works.

I also tried `"SELECT id, some_number/divisor FROM my_table"`, without any `" "` around `divisor`, but I get `error in statement: no such column: divisor`

Thanks.

Comment: See example 5 on the sqldf home page: https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
result<-sqldf(sprintf("SELECT id, some_number/%d FROM my_table", divisor))
```

Hope this helps